# send midi messages over usb with QT

Tags: qt, usb, midi

I have a usb midi effect processor that receives midi messages is there any way I can send midi messages over usb from a qt application is there a library for midi ports ?

Comment: Qt has no built-in MIDI support. What OS are you using? Could you use a library like QMidi? Why are you mentioning Qt?

Comment: Ok thanks I found qmidi,  I am using windows and I am trying to make an editor for this hardware and I am comfortable withi Qt.But I am still having problems I dont know how to open a port in qt and comunicate with this usb devise

Comment: USB MIDI devices are accessed like any other MIDI device. If you have a question about QMidi, ask a [proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RtMIDI to do that, which is C++ and can be used with Qt. As an alternative, I've published some open source libraries under the generic name "drumstick" for MIDI processing following Qt5 style and dependency. Some functionalities are multiplatform (Linux, macOS and Windows) like "drumstick-rt", which allows a Qt program to send realtime MIDI events to arbitrary MIDI outputs (USB MIDI devices or whatever). It is used for instance by my program [VMPK](http://vmpk.sf.net). Please see the [online documentation](http://drumstick.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html).